# Are the geodesics of $SO(n)$ rotation in a plane?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, geodesic

In what follows, I use "**rotation**" in a sense more closely mirroring that of everyday usage -- specifically I mean a **smooth path between two elements of $SO(n)$** (since in everyday usage a rotation means progressing through all intermediate states between the initial and final states (see for example pp. 52-53 of Stillwell's *Naive Lie Theory*, which inspired this question, in part).

Without loss of generality, let the smooth path begin at $Id \in SO(n)$ and end at some arbitrary $C \in SO(n)$ -- this is because, given any smooth path $A \to B$, we can get a path $Id \to A^{-1} B$ by taking the left action of $A^{-1}$ which is a homeomorphism (and even a diffeomorphism, I think).

> **Question:** Do the geodesics of $SO(n)$ correspond to our "intuitive sense" of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. the original position and the final position being separated by rotation through a single plane, as opposed to the possibility of having to compose multiple rotations occurring in multiple planes?
>
> Remember that I am only concerned with the geodesic path between *two* elements of $SO(n)$ here, the fact that the path is a geodesic meaning to imply that it is in some sense the "natural" path of intermediate states to rotate through in order to arrive at one position from another.

It would make some sense if this were the case, because then any such path would be an embedding of part of $SO(2)$ (the unit circle) into $SO(n)$, and $SO(2)$ is one-dimensional, thus an embedding of a compact subset of it into $SO(n)$ could conceivably be a path.

I am not quite sure how to phrase this question in a rigorous manner, although I have tried -- please let me know if anything is still unclear so that I can correct and improve the clarity of the question.

Comment: What is your Riemann metric of SO(n)?

Comment: The standard one as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$ for $N$ big enough?

Comment: Even with a bi-invariant metric, not all one-parameter subgroups are geodesics. See for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81590/one-parameter-subgroup-and-geodesics-on-lie-group

Comment: @XipanXiao Thank you for this reference! I never could have thought of the problem in those terms and thus would not have found this reference by myself. In Claudio Gorodski's answer, he says that the one-parameter group corresponding to a left-invariant vector field $X$ is a geodesic if and only if $\nabla_X X=0$. Does this condition hold for $SO(3)$? Also, are rotations inside of a plane one-parameter subgroups? I would guess so since we could parametrize by the angle $\theta$ of rotation inside of our chosen plane, but I just want to be certain that this interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Xiao In my thought if we have biinvariant metric then one-parameter group is a geodesic But If we have a left invariant metric induced from a biinvariant metric on compact Lie group, this does not hold

Answer (score 1):

Geodesic is related with a metric Since $SO(n)$ is compact so there
exists a biinvariant metric so that $$ \nabla_XY = \frac{1}{2}
[X,Y]\ \ast$$ where $X,\ Y$ are left invariant vector field.

Note that $T_ISO(n)$ is set of skew symmetric matrices And define
$$c_X(t):= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(tX)^i}{i!},\ X\in T_ISO(n)$$

Then $c_X'(t)=c_X(t) X$ so that $c_X$ is a integral curve at $I$ for
a left invariant vector field $X$ Note that by $\ast$ $c_X$ is a
geodesic

Comment: And this represents rotation inside of a single plane because it is one-parameter?